How to perform Opamp stability analysis using LTspice Frequency Response Analyzer (FRA)
Long back I asked a question about FRA is SE.That was regarding stability analysis of power supplies.
May I know how to apply FRA method to analyze the stability of Opamp circuit.
For example, can you please tell me how to apply FRA for the stability analysis of an inverting opamp.
If you can explain with an example it will be very helpful for me.

Here is the answer for using microcap v12.
Just insert the symbol "stability" (just below output vo) and use Stability Analysis.
You get this figure where you can read the Gain and Phase margins.

And here is the Nyquist figure

You can make the "same" figures with LTSpice ...

I never used this tool.But feels like it is very easy to use compared to Ltspice for stability analysis of Opamps.I believe V3 and V4 are two different inputs,do I need to make them zero when performing the stability analysis

No. Just switch the correct input. V4 can also be used for TRANsient Analysis with a rectangular wave.

Im interested for answer of this question. At the moment I use Tian and Middlebrook method for op-amp found in LTSPice example library
